# Calculate your stack exchange reputation

Tags: code-golf

**Background:**

I often find that, when browsing a Stackexchange site, I begin to wonder how people get the amount of reputation that they have. I know I can always count on codegolf SE to solve my problems, so here it is:

Create a program that will accept a positive integer which represents a person's reputation. We will ignore bounties, and say that these are the only ways to gain/lose rep on SE (full table [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)):

- Every account starts out with 1 rep and cannot go below that
- Your question is upvoted = +5
- Your answer is upvoted = +10
- Your question is downvoted = -2
- Your answer is downvoted = -2
- You downvote an answer = -1
- Your answer is accepted = +15
- You accept an answer = +2

Your program must figure out how many of those actions occurred on that user's account to get to the rep they have. It must figure out the shortest number of actions to get to this level of rep. Examples:

> Input: 11
> Output: 1 answer upvote
>
> Input: 93
> Output: 6 answer accepts, 1 answer accepted

In these examples when I say 'question upvote', it means that person's queston got upvoted. When I say 'answer downvoted', it means they downvoted someone else's answer.

**Rules:**

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code that can do this wins.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to obtain any given reputation. Only implementing "answer upvote" and "answer downvoted" is enough to always find a way, so there is no impetus to use any wider subset of the score changes. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @algorithmshark edited. You must find the smallest number of actions that will get you there

Comment: """I often find that, when browsing a Stackexchange site, I begin to wonder how people get the amount of reputation that they have.""" vs """You must find the smallest number of actions that will get you there""". The 2nd quote is not neccessarily the correct answer to the first quote.

Comment: @algorithmshark In general I agree with your comments. However 6 answer accepts + 1 answer accepted is 6*15+2=92, not 93! I can't see a way to do it in 7 actions, but I can do it in 8: 6 answer accepts, one question upvote, one question downvote: 6*15+5-2=93. Doctor, if there is more than one possibility for "smallest number of actions" do we have to find all of them or just one?

Comment: Do we need to take into account that we can downvote only after reaching certain level of rep?

Comment: @steveverrill you start with 1 rep

Comment: @ace - nope. only the rules listed above

Comment: As @Dennis shows in the explanation of his answer, this is fairly trivial now that the question has evolved from having infinite answers. Strictly, you don't say the "when I say" phrases.

Comment: I suggest to remove one of the `-2`events.

Comment: There is missing one: you get -5 reputation when a user is removed. I don't know what that means, but it's a valid one. You can check my reputation history and see for yourself. I will provide a printscreen if needed.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it's someone who upvoted an answer of yours, so you lost that upvote. I suppose for the purpose of this question that may just count as not ever having received that upvote in the first place.

Comment: I've sort-of corrected the output to the test case, in the sense that it now has an interpretation which gives the correct answer. But it's horribly ambiguous which of "answer accepts" and "answer accepted" means that I performed the action, and which means that someone else performed the action on my answer.

Comment: @m.buettner but you only lose 5, not the 10

Comment: @Ismael, sorry I meant a question, not an answer.

Comment: @m.buettner You still lose only 5, it's a totally different event.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it

Comment: @TheDoctor That gives a whole new twist to this loss of reputation for an user deleting it's account... You even have to calculate the current reputation that the user had. But still, it's a totally different event from the ones listed.

Comment: I didn't include that in the possible rep actions for a reason

Comment: bash, 23: `echo random glitch, +$1`

Comment: At least we're not all traveling salesmen.

Comment: But... association bonus?

Comment: Oh wait. You can only downvote when you have a certain rep. (And its answer only too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Golfscript, <s>162</s> 144 bytes

```
{{}if}:?;~.)15/:^15*-:~3>1~8>' answer ':A' question 'if'upvote'++?^^A'accept'+:C+^1>{'s'+}??~5%:,4<,1>&1C'ed'++?,2%!1A'downvote'++,4<{'d'+}??]n*
```

## How it works

The general idea is exactly the same as in [my Bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25060).

```
{{}if}:?;         # Create an `if' statement with an empty `else' block.
                  #
~.)15/:^          # Interpret the input string, subtract 1 from its only element (the
                  # reputation score), divide by 15 and save the result in `^'. This gives
                  # the number of accepted answers.
                  #
15*-:~            # Multiply the number of accepted answer by 15 and subtract the product
                  # from the reputation score. Save the result in `~'.
                  #
3>                # If the result is greater than 3:
                  #
  1               # Push 1 on the stack.
                  #
  ~8>             # If the result is greater than 8:
                  #
    ' answer ':A  # Push `answer' on the stack. Either way, save the string in `A'.
                  #
    ' question '  # Otherwise, push `question' on the stack.
                  #
  if              #
                  #
  'upvote'++      # Push `upvote' on the stack and concatenate the three strings.
                  #
?                 #
                  #
^                 # If the number of accepted answers is positive:
                  #
  ^A'accept'+:C+  # Push the number, concatenated with the string ` answer accept', on the
                  # stack. Either way, the string in `C'.
                  #
  ^1>             # If the number of accepted answers is greater than 1:
                  #
    {'s'+}        # Cocatenate the previous string with `s', for proper pluralization.
                  #
  ?               #
                  #
?                 #
                  #
~5%:,             # Calculate the reputation score modulus 5. Save the result in `,'.
                  #
4<,1>&            # If the result is less than 4 and greater than 1:
                  #
  1C'ed'++        # Push the string `1 answer accepted' on the stack.
                  #
?                 #
                  #
,2%!              # If the result is odd:
                  #
  1A'downvote'++  # Push the string `1 answer downvote' on the stack.
                  #
  ,4<             # If the result is less than 4:
                  #
    {'d'+}        # Concatente the previous string with `d'.
                  #
  ?               #
                  #
?                 #
                  #
]n*               # Join the array formed by all strings on the stack, separating the
                  # strings by newlines. This is the output.
```

Answer (score 9):

## Bash, <s>247</s> <s>202</s> 192 bytes

```
n=$1 bash <(sed 's/E/)echo /;s/C/ Aaccept/;s/A/answer /
s/.*)/((&)\&\&/'<<<'a=(n+1)/15,a-1)s=s;q=question
aE$aC$s
r=n%5,r-4)d=d&&
r>1E1Ced
1-r%2E1 Adownvote$d
n-=15*a,n>8)q=A
n>3E1 $q upvote')
```

#### How it works

After the *sed* command does it job, the following bash script gets executed:

```
((a=(n+1)/15,a-1))&&s=s;q=question
((a))&&echo $a answer accept$s
((r=n%5,r-4))&&d=d&&
((r>1))&&echo 1 answer accepted
((1-r%2))&&echo 1 answer downvote$d
((n-=15*a,n>8))&&q=answer 
((n>3))&&echo 1 $q upvote
```

To obtain the optimal solution (minimal number of events to get `n` reputation), it suffices to compute the number of accepted answers (`a`) necessary to get to a reputation below 16 (1 answer accept) and handle the residue as follows:

```
1  (no rep change)
2  answer accepted, answer downvoted
3  answer accepted
4  question upvote, answer downvote
5  question upvote, answer downvoted
6  question upvote
7  question upvote, answer accepted, answer downvoted
8  question upvote, answer accepted
9  answer upvote, answer downvote
10 answer upvote, answer downvoted
11 answer upvote
12 answer upvote, answer accepted, answer downvoted
13 answer upvote, answer accepted  
14 answer accept, answer downvote
15 answer accept, answer downvoted
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's not simple to deal with `-2` and `-1` downvotes.

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, <strike>500</strike> <strike>263</strike> <strike>256</strike> 208 bytes

Script `rep.pl`:

```perl
$_=1+pop;sub P($){print$=,@_,$/}$;=" answer ";$:="$;downvote";($==$_/15)&&P"$;accept"."s"x($=>1);$_%=15;$==1;P"$;upvote",$_-=10if$_>9;P" question upvote",$_-=5if$_>4;P"$;accepted"if$_>2;P$:."d"if$_%2;P$:if!$_
```

### Usage

The input is expected as positive integer, given as argument to the script. The different actions are output as lines.

### Tests

```bash
perl rep.pl 11
1 answer upvote

perl rep.pl 93
6 answer accepts
1 answer accepted

perl rep.pl 1

perl rep.pl 4
1 question upvote
1 answer downvote

perl rep.pl 12
1 answer upvote
1 answer accepted
1 answer downvoted

perl rep.pl 19
1 answer accept
1 question upvote
1 answer downvote

perl rep.pl 34
2 answer accepts
1 question upvote
1 answer downvote

perl rep.pl 127
8 answer accepts
1 question upvote
1 answer accepted
1 answer downvoted

perl rep.pl 661266
44084 answer accepts
1 question upvote
```

### Ungolfed

```perl
$_ = pop() + 1; # read the reputation as argument,
                # remove the actionless start reputation
                # and add a bias of two to calculate
                # the answer accepts in one division.

# Actions
# -------
# answer accepts:      Your answer is accepted    = +15
# answer upvotes:       Your answer is upvoted     = +10
# question upvotes:     Your question is upvoted   = +5
# answers accepted:     You accept an answer       = +2
# answers downvoted:    You downvote an answer     = -1
# answer downvotes:     Your answer is downvoted   = -2
# (questions downvoted: Your question is downvoted = -2) not used

# Function P prints the number of actions in $= and
# the action type, given in the argument.
# The function is prototyped "($)" to omit the
# parentheses in the usage.
sub P ($) {
    print $=, @_, $/ # $/ is the line end "\n"
}
# abbreviations,
# special variable names to save a space if a letter follows
$; = " answer ";
$: = "$;downvote";

# Calculation and printing the result
# -----------------------------------
($= = $_ / 15) && # integer division because of the special variable $=
P "$;accept" .
  "s" x ($= > 1); # short for: ($= == 1 ? "" : "s")
$_ %= 15;
$= = 1;           # now the action count is always 1 if the action is used
P "$;upvote",         $_ -= 10 if $_ > 9;
P " question upvote", $_ -=  5 if $_ > 4;
P "$;accepted"                 if $_ > 2;
P $: . "d"                     if $_ % 2;
P $:                           if ! $_
```

### Older version

```perl
$_ = pop() + 1; # read the reputation as argument
                # subtract start reputation (1)
                # add bias (2)

# Actions
# -------
# $= answer accepts:      Your answer is accepted    = +15
# $b answer upvotes:      Your answer is upvoted     = +10
# $c question upvotes:    Your question is upvoted   = +5
# $d answers accepted:    You accept an answer       = +2
# $e answers downvoted:   You downvote an answer     = -1
# $f answer downvotes:    Your answer is downvoted   = -2
# -- questions downvoted: Your question is downvoted = -2

# Calculaton of answer accepts by a simple division that is
# possible because of the bias.
$= = $_ / 15; # integer division because of the special variable $=
$_ %= 15;

# The older version of the calculation can be simplified further, see below.
# Also the older version did not use the bias.
#
# function E optimizes the construct "$_ == <num>" to "E <num>"
# sub E {
#     $_ == pop
# }
#
# $d = $e = 1 if E 1;       #  1 =     +2 -1
# $d++ if E 2;              #  2 =     +2
#
# $c = $f = 1 if E 3;       #  3 =  +5 -2
# $c = $e = 1 if E 4;       #  4 =  +5 -1
# $c++ if E 5;              #  5 =  +5
# $c = $d = $e = 1 if E 6;  #  6 =  +5 +2 -1
# $c = $d = 1 if E 7;       #  7 =  +5 +2
#
# $b = $f = 1 if E 8;       #  8 = +10 -2
# $b = $e = 1 if E 9;       #  9 = +10 -1
# $b++ if E 10;             # 10 = +10
# $b = $d = $e = 1 if E 11; # 11 = +10 +2 -1
# $b = $d = 1 if E 12;      # 12 = +10 +2
#
# $=++, $f++ if E 13;       # 13 = +15 -2
# $=++, $e++ if E 14;       # 14 = +15 -1

$b++, $_ -= 10 if $_ > 9;
$c++, $_ -=  5 if $_ > 4;

# Now $_ is either 0 (-2), 1 (-1), 2 (0), 3 (1), or 4 (2).
# The number in parentheses is the remaining reputation change.

# The following four lines can be further optimized. 
# $f++        if ! $_;    # "! $_" is short for "$_ == 0"
# $e++        if $_ == 1;
# $d = $e = 1 if $_ == 3;
# $d++        if $_ == 4;

# Optimized version of the previous four lines:

$f++ if ! $_;
$e++ if $_ % 2;
$d++ if $_ > 2;

# function P optimizes the printing and takes the arguments for "print";
# the first argument is the action count and the printing is suppressed,
# if this action type is not needed.
sub P {
    print @_, $/ if $_[0]
    # $/ is "\n"
}

# some abbreviations to save some bytes
$; = " answer ";
$D = "$;downvote";

# output the actions

P $=, "$;accept", ($= == 1 ? "" : "s");
P $b, "$;upvote";
P $c, " question upvote";
P $d, "$;accepted";
P $e, $D, "d";
P $f, $D
```

### Edits

- Case 4 is fixed.
- This also simplifies the calculation that is now done without a loop.
- Unreachable plural "s" removed, function `S` no longer needed.
- Calculation optimized, function `E` no longer needed.
- Bias of 2 added for optimized calculation.
- Larger rewrite to remove most variables some other tricks to save some bytes.

Comment: according to this, [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has 44084 answer accepts & 1 answer upvote

Comment: @TheDoctor: According to the question, these are the minimal number of actions to get a reputation of 661266.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>454</s> 421

```r
r=as.integer(commandArgs(T)[1])-1;p=function(...){paste(...,sep='')};a='answer ';b='accept';e='ed';f='d';v='vote';d=p('down',v);u=p('up',v);q='question ';z=c();t=r%/%15;if(t>0){z=c(p(t,' ',a,b));r=r%%15;};if(r%in%(8:12))z=c(z,p(a,u));if(r%in%(3:7))z=c(z,p(q,u));if(r%in%c(1,2,6,7,11,12))z=c(z,p(a,b,e));if(r%in%(13:14))z=c(z,p(a,b));if(r%in%c(3,8,13))z=c(z,p(a,d));if(r%in%c(1,4,6,9,11,14))z=c(z,p(a,d,f));cat(z,sep=', ')
```

Thanks to Dennis for [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25060/10619) which helped me a lot.

### Ungolfed version

```r
# read input
r = as.integer(commandArgs(T)[1]) - 1

# shortcut to join strings (... will pass the parameter to paste() *as is*)
p = function(...) {paste(..., sep = '')}

# strings
a = 'answer '; b = 'accept'; e = 'ed'; f = 'd'
v = 'vote'; d = p('down',v); u = p('up',v)
q = 'question '

z = c()

# +15
t = r %/% 15;
if (t > 0) {
    z = c(p(t,' ',a,b))
    r = r %% 15
}

if (r %in% (8:12))              z = c(z,p(a,u));    # answer upvote
if (r %in% (3:7))               z = c(z,p(q,u));    # question upvote
if (r %in% c(1,2,6,7,11,12))    z = c(z,p(a,b,e));  # answer accepted
if (r %in% (13:14))             z = c(z,p(a,b));    # answer accept
if (r %in% c(3,8,13))           z = c(z,p(a,d));    # answer downvote
if (r %in% c(1,4,6,9,11,14))    z = c(z,p(a,d,f));  # answer downvoted

# print operations
cat(z,sep = ', ')
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript - <s>270</s> <s>237</s> <s>227</s> <s>206</s> 192 characters

```
p=prompt,r=p()-1,a="1answer ",v="vote,";s=(r/15|0)+"answer accept,",r%=15;if(r>9)s+=a+"+"+v,r-=10;if(r>2)s+="1question +"+v,r-=5;r>0?s+=a+"accepted,":0;r<-1?s+=a+"-"+v:0;p(r&1?s+=a+"-voted":s)
```

Exactly as many chars as Bash (yeah!), and beats Python and Perl :) It cuts down the reputation until `14` after which it takes after which it takes the other necessary actions, completely loop-style.

EDIT 1: Converted `\n`s to `,`s and converted one `if` block to ternary, and better flooring with short names.

EDIT 2: Big thanks to [Alconja](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17365/alconja) who helped me cut down **11** chars. After which I made some more corrections to cut down 2 more chars.

---

**Older Version:**

```
r=prompt()-1,a="1answer ",q="1question ",v="vote,";s=(c=r/15|0)+"answer accept,",r-=c*15;if(r>9)s+=a+"+"+v,r-=10;if(r>2)s+=q+"+"+v,r-=5;r>0?s+=a+"accepted,":0;if(r<-1)s+=a+"-"+v;r&1?s+=a+"-voted":0;alert(s)
```

---

### Test:

**INPUT:** `42`
**OUTPUT:**

```
2answer accept,1answer +vote,1answer accepted,1answer -voted

/*I sincerely hope the output is clear and easy to make out*/
```

**INPUT:** `1337`
**OUTPUT:**

```
89answer accept,1answer accepted,1answer -voted
```

---

### Ungolfed Code:

```
// different version from the golfed code
rep = prompt() - 1
string = ""

function $(z, c, k){
  while(rep > 0 && rep >= z - 2) c += 1 , rep -= z;

  if(c) string += c + k + "\n"
}

a=" answer ", q=" question "

$(15, 0, a + "accept")
$(10, 0, a + "upvote")
$(5, 0, q + "upvote")
$(2, 0, a + "accepted")

function _(z, c, str){
  while(rep <= z) c += 1, rep -= z

  if(c) string += c + str + "\n";
}

_(-2, 0, a + "downvote");
_(-1, 0, a + "downvoted");

alert(string);
```

Comment: Why is the first one Firefox only?

Comment: @TheDoctor It utilizes the feature of JS currently available only in Firefox - `function name(args){}` becomes `name=(args)=>{}` and thus saves a lot of bytes.

Comment: @TheDoctor I have updated my program to be cross-browser, and it is now much shorter than before !

Comment: Your current version only uses `q` once, so you can inline it. Also, you can drop the `c` variable and do a `r%=15` instead of `r-=c*15`. Should bring you down to 195 chars (`r=prompt()-1,a="1answer ",v="vote,";s=(r/15|0)+"answer accept,",r%=15;if(r>9)s+=a+"+"+v,r-=10;if(r>2)s+="1question +"+v,r-=5;r>0?s+=a+"accepted,":0;if(r<-1)s+=a+"-"+v;r&1?s+=a+"-voted":0;alert(s)`).

Comment: @Alconja Wow! Thanks a lot! I finally am very very close to Bash ! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Alconja And with some more corrections, I am exactly at par with Bash :D

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - <strike>273</strike> <strike>256</strike> 235

```
p=prompt(s=j="\n")-1;z=" answer",w=" accept",x=" upvoted"+j,y=w+"ed",v=" question",u=" downvoted";if(m=p/15|0)s+=m+z+y+j;r=p-m*15;if(m=r/10|0)s+=m+z+x;r-=m*10;if(m=r/5|0)s+=m+v+x;r-=m*5;n=r/2|0;if(m=r-=n*2)n++,s+=m+u+z+j;alert(s+n+y+z)
```

Combined calculation and output, and golfed further to a total of 287.

Edit: took out some variables for a few shorter.

Removed Math.Floor for |0 approach.

Moved some initialisation to the prompt() param, removed some brackets, alert with final string append.

Comment: Welcome to codegolf.SE ! The instructions say: "Create a program that will accept a positive integer" -> so you will need to use `prompt`, and can't hard code the value.

Comment: No worries, added prompt(), which bumps it up to 161.

Comment: Following @GaurangTandon's smarter prompt()-1 and alert output approach to get this down further. Reduced some of the hardcoded string storage too.

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 391

A bit long, and I haven't tested this thoroughly (much). :)

```cs
class R{void Main(string[] a){var r=int.Parse(a[0])-1;var a=new[]{15,10,5,2};var o=new List<string>();Func<int,string>y=z=>{var w="";if(z==15)w=" answer accepted";if(z==10)w=" answer upvotes";if(z==5)w=" question upvotes";if(z==2)w=" answer accepts";return w;};foreach(var x in a)if(r/x>0){o.Add(r/x+y(x));r-=(r/x)*x;}if(r==1)o.Add("1 question downvotes");Console.Write(string.Join(", ",o));
```

**Un-golfed - NEW**

```cs
class R
{
    void Main(string[] a)
    {
        var r = int.Parse("122")-1; // subtracts 1 from total rep
        var a = new[] {15,10,5,2};
        var o = new List<string>();
        
        Func<int,string> y = 
            z => 
                {
                    var w="";
                    if(z==15) w=" answer accepted";
                    if(z==10) w=" answer upvotes";
                    if(z==5) w=" question upvotes";
                    if(z==2) w=" answer accepts";
                    return w;
                };
        
        foreach(var x in a) {
            if (r/x>0) {
                o.Add(r/x+y(x));
                r-=(r/x)*x;
            }
        }
            
        if(r==1)
            o.Add("1 question downvotes");
            
        Console.Write(string.Join(", ",o));
    }
}
```

**Un-golfed - OLD (409)**

```cs
class R
{
    void Main(string[] a)
    {
        var r = int.Parse(a[0])-1; // subtracts 1 from total rep
        var v = new[] {" question"," answer"," downvotes"," upvotes"," accepts"," accepted"};
        var o = new List<string>();
        
        // Starts from 15, then checks all the lower values.
        if (r/15>0) {
            o.Add(r/15+v[1]+v[5]);
            r-=(r/15)*15; // automatic rounding down due to int
        }
        if(r/10>0) {
            o.Add(r/10+v[1]+v[3]);
            r-=(r/10)*10;
        }
        if(r/5>0) {
            o.Add(r/5+v[0]+v[3]);
            r-=(r/5)*5;
        }
        if(r/2>0) {
            o.Add(r/2+v[1]+v[4]);
            r-=(r/2)*2;
        }
        if(r==1) {
            o.Add("1"+v[0]+v[2]);
        }
        Console.Write(string.Join(", ",o));
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```cs
> prog.exe 120

7 answer accepted, 1 answer upvotes, 2 answer accepts
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python - <strike>213</strike> 207**

```
p,k=__import__('itertools').combinations_with_replacement,int(input())
t,m,u=[5,10,-2,-1,15,2],[],iter(range(0,k))
while not m:m=list(filter(lambda v:k-1==sum(v),p(t,next(u))))
print(''.join(map(chr,m[0])))
```

Curse you long function names!

Example: (ignore the trailing newline)

```
$ echo "93" | python per.py | hexdump -C
00000000  0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 02 0a                           |........|

$ echo "11" | python per.py | hexdump -C
00000000  0a 0a                                             |..|
```

Comment: How do you display number of questions and answers votes, etc.? Your code doesn't contain these strings (see the other answers), so I'm afraid the output is not compliant with the rules.

Comment: The output is golfed too since there was no requirement about that. It doesn't treat downvoted question/answers separately as both give -2 points, the resulting list that is printed is the shortest sequence to achieve the score.

Comment: Yes, the rules don't go into details about this point. But you can notice that in the other answers the output is standard and display *X answer accepts*, *Y answer upvotes*, etc. But that's not a problem since you don't have the shortest code.

Comment: @LemonBoy I have tried this on three interpreters and it doesn't work. All say `EOF`. Can you please point me to a compiler which works (and which I should keep for future reference) ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon I've tested it with both python2.7.6/3.4.0 and works just fine.

Comment: @LemonBoy That's great! But I am asking you to point me to the online interpreter where you have tested, so I keep it for future reference when I learn Python.

Comment: @GaurangTandon huh? I've tested it with my local install of python. Anyway the first site that popped up when I searched for an online python repl, repl.it, runs the code just fine.

Comment: @LemonBoy Looks like it's something wrong with me, here's the code I pasted http://repl.it/Qth looks good, I don't know why it gives an error ...

Comment: @GaurangTandon sigh, you're trying to run Python code using the coffeescript interpreter

Answer (score 1):

### Game Maker Language, 276

```
p=real(keyboard_string())-1j="#"s=""z=" answer"w=" accept"x=" upvoted"+j;y=w+"ed"v=" question"u=" downvoted"if m=floor(p/15)s+=(m+z+y)+j;r=p-m*15if m=floor(r/10)s+=(m+z+x)r-=m*10if m=floor(r/5)s+=(m+v+x)r-=m*5n=floor(r/2)r-=n*2if m=r{n++;s+=(m+u+z)+j}s+=(n+y+z)show_message(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 276 (316 w/ includes)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
p(int&q,int*d){int r;char*s[]={"downvoted","accepted","question","answer","upvoted"};
if(r=(q&&q>=*d)){q-=(*d?*d:2);printf("%s %s\n",s[*(++d)],s[*(++d)]);}return r;}main(
int n,char**v){int q=atoi(v[1]);int d[]={-1,3,0,0,3,1,5,4,2,10,4,3,15,1,3};n=15;while
(p(q,d+n-3)||(n-=3));}
```

Compiles with GCC, with warnings. Example:

```
$ ./a.out 0
$ ./a.out 1
accepted answer
downvoted answer
$ ./a.out 2
accepted answer
$ ./a.out 5
question upvoted
$ ./a.out 10
answer upvoted
$ ./a.out 15
answer accepted
$ ./a.out 16
answer accepted
accepted answer
downvoted answer
$ ./a.out 17
answer accepted
accepted answer
```

Feel free to port this to a language that doesn't require type declarations and post it as your own.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 188B

```
n=input()+1
a=n//15
n%=15
A='answer '
print("%d %saccepted\n%d %supvoted\n%d question upvoted\n%d accept %s\n%d downvote %s\n%d %sdownvoted"%(a,A,n//10,A,n%10//5,n%5>2,A,n%5%2,A,n%5==0,A))
```

Usage: `python3 score.py <ret> 11 <ret>` where this script is saved as score.py.

Sample output:

```
$ python score.py
5543
369 answer accepted
0 answer upvoted
1 question upvoted
1 accept answer 
0 downvote answer 
0 answer downvoted
```

Comment: accepted = accept + d, downvoted = downvote + d, upvoted is repeated.

Comment: Yes but those substitutions don't save any characters overall - try it and see