# Help recalculate your rep!

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

A couple months ago, we had a [discussion on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7683/42545) about increasing the reputation awarded for upvotes on questions. Here's the basics of our current reputation system for votes:<sup>1</sup>

- A question upvote `U` is worth 5 reputation.
- An answer upvote `u` is worth 10 reputation.
- A question or answer downvote `d` is worth -2 reputation.

There have been many different suggestions for a new system, but the current most popular is identical to the above, but with question upvotes scaled to +10 rep. This challenge is about calculating how much more rep you would earn if this system were put into place.

Let's look at an example. If the voting activity was `UUUUuuuuUUUUUduuudUU`, then you'd earn 121 under the current system:

```
U x 4 x  5 =  20 =  20
u x 4 x 10 =  40 =  60
U x 5 x  5 =  25 =  85
d x 1 x -2 =  -2 =  83
u x 3 x 10 =  30 = 113
d x 1 x -2 =  -2 = 111
U x 2 x  5 =  10 = 121
Total:             121
```

But the same activity would earn 176 under the new system:

```
U x 4 x 10 =  40 =  40
u x 4 x 10 =  40 =  80
U x 5 x 10 =  50 = 130
d x 1 x -2 =  -2 = 128
u x 3 x 10 =  30 = 158
d x 1 x -2 =  -2 = 156
U x 2 x 10 =  20 = 176
Total:             176
```

You would gain **55 rep** from this scenario.

So far, calculating the changed rep isn't that hard; just count the number of `U`s and multiply by 5. Fortunately, the rep system isn't that simple: there is also a **rep cap**, which is the most reputation you can earn from votes in one UTC day. This is set to 200 on all sites.

Also, the rep cap applies in real time: if you have already earned 196 rep and you receive an answer upvote, you will now have 200 rep. If you get a downvote right after that, the 2 rep will be subtracted from 200, so you will have 198 rep.

With the voting activity `UUUuuuuUUUUuuuuUUUUUUUd`, you would earn 148 rep under the current system:

```
U x 3 x  5 =  15 =  15
u x 4 x 10 =  40 =  55
U x 4 x  5 =  20 =  75
u x 4 x 10 =  40 = 115
U x 7 x  5 =  35 = 150
d x 1 x -2 =  -2 = 148
Total:             148
```

But you would earn 198 under the new system:

```
U x 3 x 10 =  30 =  30
u x 4 x 10 =  40 =  70
U x 4 x 10 =  40 = 110
u x 4 x 10 =  40 = 150
U x 7 x 10 =  70 = 200 (rep capped)
d x 1 x -2 =  -2 = 198
Total:             198
```

Thus, the increase is **50 rep**.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program or function that takes in a multi-line string and outputs the total rep that would be gained with the above algorithm. Each line counts as 1 UTC day, so the rep cap only applies once per line.

#### Test cases

(One or more lines of input, followed by the output integer.)

```
UUUuudd
15

UUUuUUUUuUuuUUUUudUUUUuU
57

UUUuUUUUuUuuUUUUudUUUUuU
UUUuudd
72

uuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
0

UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
5

(empty string)
0

UUUuuuuuUUUuuUUUUUUuuuUUUuuUUUUuuuuUUUdddddddUU
4

UUUuuuuuUUUuuUUUUUUuuuUUUuuUUUUuuuuUUUdddddddUU
UuuUUUudUU
UUUUUUUUUuuuuuuUUUUUUuuUUUUUUuuuuuUUUUUUUUuUUUuuuuUUUUuuuUUUuuuuuuUUUUUUUUuuUUUuuUU
UUu
U
d
UU
UUUUUUUUUUUU
119
```

**This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.**

<sup>Related challenges: [Calculate the bounded cumulative sum of a vector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61684/42545), [Calculate your stack exchange reputation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25047/42545)</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is a highly simplified version of the system. You also lose 1 rep for downvoting an answer, and there exist unupvotes, which [are weird and follow rules of their own](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27282054#27282054); and undownvotes, which [don't even have rules to follow](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25083191#25083191).</sup>

Comment: Nice challenge. Too bad it's [not likely to happen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27434156#27434156)...

Comment: ¹ You don't lose rep for downvoting questions; just answers. Trust me :P

Comment: @Mego Possible, but I see the following differences: A) The full cumulative array isn't needed, just the last term. B) There is no lower bound, and the upper bound is fixed. C) The input is a string, as opposed to an array of numbers. D) Arbitrary amounts of these strings, separated by newlines, must be each run through separately and summed to get the result.

Comment: @ETHproductions All of those except B are I/O differences. The core problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Perl, <s>104</s> 91 + 2 = 93 bytes

```
sub f{200*$.>$_[0]?$_[0]:200*$.}for(/./g){$a=/d/?-2:10;$s=f$s+$a;$o=f$o+$a-5*/U/}}{$_=$s-$o
```

Requires the `-p` flag:

```
$ echo UUUuUUUUuUuuUUUUudUUUUuU | perl -p recalc.pl
57
$ echo "UUUuUUUUuUuuUUUUudUUUUuU
UUUuudd" | perl -p recalc.pl
72
```

Breakdown:

```
sub f {
  # '$.' contains the line number (1, 2, ... n)
  200*$. > $_[0] ? $_[0] : 200*$.
}
for(/./g){
  $a= /d/ ? -2  : 10;
  $s=f( $s + $a );
  # /U/ returns `1` if true
  $o=f( $o + $a - 5*/U/ )
}
}{ # Eskimo exit while loop (do this after the outer (from -p) iteration)
$_=$s-$o
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>98</s> 93 bytes

Thanks to BlackCap to golf this further. Now, I think to try lambda in later challenges, now.

```
x#'U'=x
_#'u'=10
_#'d'=(-2)
a&b=foldl1(\d g->min 200$d+a#g)
g=sum.map(\x->(10&x)-(5&x)).lines
```

The first 3 lines is the scoring, a&b is is the score, f is the difference and the g is the function sastifying the specification.

Usage:

```
g"UUUuuuuuUUUuuUUUUUUuuuUUUuuUUUUuuuuUUUdddddddUU" -- 4
```

Comment: You can merge the two last lines and earn 1 byte: g=sum.map(\x->(10&x)-(5&x)).lines
You can also remove the parentheses for another four bytes: g=sum.map(\x->10&x-5&x).lines

Comment: And 3 more bytes if you merge the map and the fold: a&b=foldl(\d g->min 200$d+a#g)0b

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 104 bytes

```
s=>s.split`
`.map(l=>(g=U=>[...l].map(c=>(r+=eval(c))>200?r=200:0,r=0)|r,t+=g(10)-g(5)),u=10,d=-2,t=0)|t
```

Calculates the before and after rep for each line. My first use of `eval`!

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 196 Bytes

This program takes a single multi-line argument as input, and print the total difference in rep'

```lua
e,f,a=0,0,{u=10,U=10,d=-2}arg[1]:gsub(".-\n",function(s)x=0 y=0 s:gsub("[^\n]",function(c)t=x+a[c]x,t=t>199 and 200 or t,y+a[c]-(c<"V"and 5 or 0)y=t>199 and 200 or t end)e=e+x f=f+y end)print(e-f)
```

I assumed I am allowed to ask for a trailing new line in the input, if I'm not, here's a 204 Bytes solution that doesn't need it.

```lua
e,f,a=0,0,{u=10,U=10,d=-2}(arg[1].."\n"):gsub(".-\n",function(s)x=0 y=0 s:gsub("[^\n]",function(c)t=x+a[c]x,t=t>199 and 200 or t,y+a[c]-(c<"V"and 5 or 0)y=t>199 and 200 or t end)e=e+x f=f+y end)print(e-f)
```

#### Ungolfed and explanations

```lua
a={u=10,U=10,d=-2}            -- define the table containing the vote values
e,f=0,0                       -- initialize the total sums of rep'

arg[1]:gsub(".-\n",function(s)-- iterate over each line
  x=0                         -- score by the new scoring method for this UTC day
  y=0                         -- score by the old method
  s:gsub("[^\n]",function(c)  -- iterate over each non new-line character
    t=x+a[c]                  -- new score for today
    x=t>199 and 200 or t      -- reduce it to 200 if >=200
                        -- Do the same thing with the old scoring method
    t=y+a[c]-(c<"V"and 5 or 0)-- if c=="U", this question vote gives only 5
    y=t>199 and 200 or t      
  end)
  e=e+x f=f+y                 -- sum the scores over multiple days
end)
print(e-f)                    -- output the difference
```